# Need daily count of whole month - SQL2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to generate simple report which gives me Failed test count daily for whole month. Is there a way to write a sql query that does that? Rather then running queries by changing dates? This is what i am doing:

```
select count (*) from students where Message Like 'Failed Test.%'
and Timestamp > '01-01-2013' and Timestamp < '01-02-2013'
```

So above query gives me count 5. Then i change the date from 01-01 to 01-02 and get next days count and so on. But this seems like very time consuming thing. Just checking if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: I think you need a date table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives counts grouped by day for a month's date range:

```
select cast(timestamp as date) as [Date], count (*) as NumFailedTests
from students 
where Message Like 'Failed Test.%'
and Timestamp between '2013-01-01' and '2013-01-31'
group by cast(timestamp as date)
order by cast(timestamp as date)
```

You can obviously widen the date range...

[Hopefully the 'timestamp' column is not really a timestamp...]

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - Thank you soooo much! I cannot belive it you answered that in minutes.

Comment: I leave comment under `Timestamp > '2013-01-01' and Timestamp < '2013-02-01'` which you've already edited.

Comment: @MitchWheat - If i want to select "distinct" NumFailedTests. Where should i add distinct? I tried adding in front of NumFailedTests but it gives error?

Comment: MitchWheat - Sorry i had to wait 7 min. to select the answer dont have that prevelage. I accepted it now.

Comment: @MitchWheat - I figured it out: Count (Distinct [NumFailedTests]) as NumFailedTests. Thanks!